# How do I troubleshoot an error with 'react-native' and cocopods on a Mac using Rosetta

Tags: macos, react-native, cocoapods, rosetta

I am trying to execute a react native project on new Mac computer with app chip.
Changed the terminal to open with Rosetta as suggested in some forums

Installed the cocoa pods 1.10.1 version
Using NPM 14.16.0 and react Native version 0.63.4 and Xcode version 12.4
and tried to run the pod install command in iOS folder. I am getting the following error.

error

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined method `react_native_post_install' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00000001572d90f8>

/Users/vvvvv/WebstormProjects/Reer/ios/Podfile:27:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in `generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you post your Podfile configuration, seems like you are executing a method on the post install that it is not created in the Podfile

Comment: I'm having same problem with Intel CPU Mac. Did you solve id?
On another 0.63.4 version project I can build app, but current one throw the same error you have.

Answer (score 10):

tldr: Update your version of `react-native` to match your Podfile.

The `react_native_post_install` was introduced in `"react-native": "0.64.0"`.

For me I had `"react-native": "~0.63.4"` installed, but was using a Podfile (copy/pasted) from a 0.64 fresh `reactive-native init`.

I experienced this moving my expo-created project to raw react-native.

Comment: I upgraded react-native to 0.64.0 and it worked, thanks

Comment: Issue resolved after upgrading to 0.64.0